# grep full sentences containing a word into a document

Tags: bash, shell, grep, sentence

I would like to **extract a full sentence "." to "."** into a document given a word.
So for example given this text:

> Dijkstra's original algorithm does not use a min-priority queue. For a
>   given source vertex (node) in the graph, the algorithm finds the path
>   with lowest cost (i.e. the shortest path) between that vertex and
>   every other vertex. It can also be used for finding costs of shortest
>   paths from a single vertex to a single destination vertex by stopping
>   the algorithm once the shortest path to the destination vertex has
>   been determined.

I would like to have the **entire sentence** that contains "graph"

> For a given source vertex (node) in the graph, the algorithm finds
>   the path with lowest cost (i.e. the shortest path) between that vertex
>   and every other vertex.

Also it would be useful to find a way to include in the results the starting sentence if it contains graph, because there is no dot before it.

Comment: For things that would catch complex words with dots that doesn't end a sentence, I believe `grep` would not be enough for that. It could go *hacky enough* but still not enough. So good luck.

Comment: Yes, things like "Mr." or "Dr." or any abbreviation would throw this off.  You'd need a master list of what's an abbreviation.  And you could still have an abbreviation at the end of the sentence, like: "Mary lives in the U.S."

Comment: yeah thats right.. with abbreviations it would be tricky.. :(

Comment: In the original file, are all paragraphs on the same "logical line" -- or is there some `\n` lurking around for formatting purpose?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the text file `dijk` doesn't actually contain any newlines, you could do this in perl:

```
perl -MLingua::EN::Sentence=get_sentences -ne '
print "$_\n" for grep { /graph/ } @{get_sentences($_)}' dijk
```

The [Lingua::EN::Sentence module](http://search.cpan.org/%7Eshlomoy/Lingua-EN-Sentence-0.25/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm) is smart enough to deal with well-known abbreviations and you can add your own if necessary.

Output:

```
For a given source vertex (node) in the graph, the algorithm finds the path with lowest cost (i.e. the shortest path) between that vertex and every other vertex.
```

If the newlines do actually exist in the input, it should be possible to adapt the script without too much difficulty.

---

#### edit

If there are newlines in the input, you could do this instead:

```
perl -MLingua::EN::Sentence=get_sentences -00 -e '
$t = <>;         # slurp the whole file
$t =~ tr{\n}{ }; # convert newlines to spaces
print "$_\n" for grep { /graph/ } @{get_sentences($t)}' dijk
```

Of course, by now this is looking a lot more like a full-blown perl script rather than a one-liner!

Alternatively, as mentioned by @mklement0, you could use the external tool `tr` to perform the translation and pass the result to the original script:

```
perl -MLingua::EN::Sentence=get_sentences -ne '
print "$_\n" for grep { /graph/ } @{get_sentences($_)}' <(tr '\n' ' ' < dijk)
```

Comment: it has newline. Thanks :) I'll try it

Comment: @user3702916 I have edited my answer to show how you could deal with newlines in the input.

Comment: @user3702916 thanks for accepting my answer. Just so you know I've edited the second example again as it contained some unnecessary code.

Comment: @mklement0 I've edited my answer to include your suggestion as an alternative.

Comment: @TomFenech: I appreciate that, thanks (though, unlike what I originally thought, this is essentially just a slightly more modular stylistic variant).

Answer (score 1):

A crude heuristic:

```
cat text |
    tr '\n' ' ' |
    sed 's|[[:alpha:]]\{3\}\.[[:blank:]]*|&\'$'\n''|g' |
    grep -Fi 'graph'
```

- First, `tr` remove all end-of-lines in the input file (don't know if this is required for you)
- Then, `sed` put each sentence on its own line, *assuming* a dot preceded by three letters denotes the end of a sentence. Depending your input file, you might need to adjust this part to lower the "false positive" rate
- Finally, a simple `grep` will keep only the sentences containing the required word (case insensitive).

Given your input file, this will produce the following result:

> For a given source vertex (node) in the graph, the algorithm finds the path with lowest cost (i.e. the shortest path) between that vertex and every other vertex.

---

<sub>This answer has been made POSIX-compliant with the kind help of *mklement0*</sub>

<sub>(see comments below)</sub>

Comment: interesting :)  I'm running it on Mac os, do you know if the sed parameters are compatible? I get this message: sed: 1: "s|[a-ZA-Z]{3}\.|&\n|g": RE error: invalid character range

Comment: @user3702916 Try `[[:alpha:]]` instead of `[a-zA-Z]`.

Comment: this part: sed -E 's|[[:alpha:]]{3}\.|&\n|g' | \ doesn't work on mac it inserts "n" in the text. I found this command that works on mac:
echo "a,b" | sed -e $'s/,/\\\n/g' could you help me to fix it?thanks

Comment: Clever approach. The `awk` command will _drop_ words if they're immediately followed by a newline, immediately followed by a non-whitespace char. - better to use `tr '\n' ' '`. To make the `sed` command work on a Mac, use `sed -E 's|[[:alpha:]]{3}\.|&\'$'\n''|g'`. The overall result will have a leading space. (As an aside - I'm only mentioning it because I recently discovered it myself: no need for `\ ` (line continuation char.) after a `|` - if the command needs further tokens, it'll automatically look on the next line; therefore also works with `&&` and `||`).

Comment: @mklement0 Of course! `tr`... While writing the answer, I had the feeling that `awk` was overkill, but couldn't make my mind on it :D Silly am I...

Comment: Would you mind updating your answer (I'd up-vote then)? Also, if you additionally drop the `-E` from your `sed` command and modify the regex slightly, you get an overall POSIX-compliant solution: `cat text | tr '\n' ' ' | sed 's|[[:alpha:]]\{3\}\.|&\'$'\n''|g' | grep -Fi 'graph'`

Comment: @mklement0 Thank you for your help. I didn't have much time this afternoon, that's why I haven't made the proposed modifications before. Now this is done. Please note I add an extra `[[:blank]]*` to consume spaces after the dot -- if I'm not wrong (it's late here in France), that will remove the leading space. As far as I can tell, this works as expected on Linux. Can't test on MacOS X, though...

Comment: Thanks for updating; +1. Works fine on a Mac.

Answer (score 0):

`grep -o "\.([^.\r\n]+\.)" inputfile > outputfile`

If there are no line breaks in the original file than it's a little simpler:

`grep -o "\.([^.]+\.)" inputfile > outputfile`

Comment: could you explain better your command? where should I put the word "graph"?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it.

```
tr '\n' ' ' < input.txt | tr '.' '\n' | grep graph > output.txt
```

It converts all newlines into spaces (so that the whole text is on a single line). It then converts all `.`s into newlines so that you one sentence per line. It then greps for the relevant string and puts the matched sentences into the output file.

When run on your paragraph, it sort of works but the `.` in `i.e.` confuses it. That can be rectified by changing a few fixed strings like `i.e.` and `e.g.` into `ie` and `eg` for the process.